# Using dictionary comprehension on pd.dataframe value objects

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary with pd.DataFrame objects as dictionary values:

```
key_names=['country_1','country_2','country_3']

data_1 = [['Alex',10],['Bob',11],['Clarke',4]]
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1,columns=['Name','Age'])

data_2 = [['Tom',13],['Zoe',21],['Tom',13]]
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_1,columns=['Name','Age'])

data_3 = [['Felix',16],['Rich',22],['Phil',23]]
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(data_1,columns=['Name','Age'])

dfs=[df_1,df_2,df_3]

wb_dict=dict(zip(key_names,dfs))
```

I am trying to lower case every text inside the pd.DataFrames
& I have been succesful doing so with a for loop:

```
for k,v in wb_dict.items(): 
    wb_dict[k]=wb_dict[k].astype(str).apply(lambda x:x.str.lower())
```

and with .apply() inside a dict comprehension

```
wb_dict= {k: wb_dict[k].astype(str).apply(lambda x:x.str.lower()) for k, v in wb_dict.items()}
```

but both  these methods seem slower than they need be.

I've tried avoiding the .apply() which I believe is what slows it down. I'm coming up short:

```
{(lambda x:x.str.lower()) for x in  wb_dict[k].astype(str) for k, v in wb_dict.items()}
```

the result is a bunch of lambda function objects.

Comment: don't use `.apply`, use `.str.lower()`, and also, don't do it to the numeric fields? So, for `for k, df in wb_dict: wb_dict[k]['Name'] = df['Name'].str.lower()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `assign` to overwrite existing column values. Note that similar to your loop, this makes numeric columns (such as "Age") dtype object columns which is probably not something you want to do.

```
out = {k: df.assign(**{col: df[col].astype(str).str.lower() for col in df.columns}) for k, df in wb_dict.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'country_1':      Name Age
 0    alex  10
 1     bob  11
 2  clarke   4,
 'country_2':      Name Age
 0    alex  10
 1     bob  11
 2  clarke   4,
 'country_3':      Name Age
 0    alex  10
 1     bob  11
 2  clarke   4}
```